# Replicating a docker registry from azure to aws

Tags: docker-registry, azure-container-registry, aws-ecr

I'm searching for a replication solution for a private docker registry from azure to aws (managed container service aws **ecr**, or my own private hosted docker registry if needed, hopefully not). is there a builtin docker registry option to do that? or other known solution? or perhaps another registry provider that is hosted in AWS - east? my google foo failed me this time.

Please note: This is a question about replication, not about one time migration. Our main registry would still be in azure container registry

Answer (score 0):

There is no native replication options across ACR and ECR. You might be able to integrate with the webhooks and replicate delete/push using the digest and tag to ECR. This might require a custom job (jenkins/VSTS/VM) etc.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about how would this kind of workflow look like?  So I can accept this answer (No need to be specific about CI setup, ut about digest/tag delete/push workflow and webhooks)